# how can I found the crash, Android

Tags: android

I'm Facing a problem here, which is that; the app keeps stopped; 
I tried to solve this by the handler but it does not work; 
I'm not using a button in XML that's why I'm not giving it an id.
the app should print out time-consuming by clicking on the screen

I'm new in Android studio word. please help
here is the java file:

```
          package com.example.influencing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        runth();
    }

    public void runth() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        button.setText("Iteration = " + i);
                            }
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

here is logcat;

```
2019-03-16 04:00:21.188 6681-6681/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-03-16 04:00:21.587 6681-6681/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-03-16 04:00:22.653 6681-6681/com.example.influencing I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-03-16 04:00:23.198 6681-6699/com.example.influencing D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2019-03-16 04:00:23.439 6681-6699/com.example.influencing I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-03-16 04:00:23.440 6681-6699/com.example.influencing I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-03-16 04:00:23.440 6681-6699/com.example.influencing D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-03-16 04:00:23.441 6681-6699/com.example.influencing W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-03-16 04:00:23.441 6681-6699/com.example.influencing D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-03-16 04:00:23.512 6681-6699/com.example.influencing D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe2f850c0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-03-16 04:00:23.525 6681-6692/com.example.influencing I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 8622(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 58% free, 1109KB/2MB, paused 822us total 287.967ms
```

Comment: Post your logcat.

Comment: Post Logcat of Error messeges, not backgrond of running device

Comment: You need to look at the error messages in the log, these are just regular debug/warning messages completely unrelated

Comment: Post logcat error

Answer (score 0):

The problem because you haven't add the Button to your parent layout. You need to attach the button to the layout parent view. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // assuming you have the LinearLayout in your activity_main layout.
    LinearLayout llyParent = findViewById(R.id.parent_lly);

    roomName = etAddARoom.getText().toString();
    button = new Button(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    llyParent.addView(button);

    ...
}
```

or if you don't want to use the layout at all, you can try the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // parent layout 
    LinearLayout llyParent = new LinearLayout(this);
    llyParent.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    llyParent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Button button = new Button(this);
    llyParent.addView(button, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    setContentView(llyParent);
}
```